# How to revive an old question

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, specific-question

So let’s say I post a question and it doesn’t get answered, drifting into oblivion.
Is there a way to pump some new life into it, or do I have to delete it and post it again?

Comment: bounties are the standard way, if you have enough rep

Comment: are you talking about your question that is only 10 hours old? That's not even close to 'drifting into oblivion' - remember that we are an international community and there are spikes of activity at certain times of the day- when it gets to be a week, then we are in 'oblivion' territory

Comment: No, not talking about that one, talking about others that I’ve had to delete for this same reason, here and in other comunities.

Comment: why delete them?

Comment: For example, I had a Kali Linux question that went unanswered for quite some time. I decided to delete and to repost it, but got a quality of question alert, and wasn't able to do it. Since seeing your comment, I've reconsidered, and undeleted it.

Comment: Bash - please read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: @RoryAlsop Thanks for that info! Will take it into account. I’ll try to do something about that post and edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers):

> What should I do if no one answers my question?
>
> First, make sure you’ve [asked a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question to the homepage and get more people interested in it.
>
> If, despite your best efforts, you feel questions aren’t getting good answers, you can help by [offering a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/bounty) on any question more than two days old.

There are also some suggestions on the [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/133872) FAQ entry, namely editing with updates as you've continued to work on it, posting a link in [SE chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=security.stackexchange.com), and posting a link on social networks.